# How to display serial number in meteor template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I need to display a list of items in my meteor app.
My template code is like

```
 Template.templatename.vname = function(){
    return Groups.find();
 }


{{#each vname}}
// Need to display serial number here.
{{ field1 }}
{{/each}}
```

How can I display the serial number in this loop ?

Comment: What is `list`? An array of serial numbers (strings)?

Comment: its an array of names.I need to display the serial number before each name.

Comment: How do you store the serial numbers corresponding to the names? Without some more code this question is not clear at all.

Comment: Do you mean a the index in the list or a unique string to identify the db entry?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution

```
Template.templatename.vname = function(){
   var gps_crs = Groups.find();
   var gps = gps_crs.fetch();
   for (var i = 0; i < gps.length; i++) {
        gps[i].index = i+1;
    }
    return gps;
 }


{{#each vname}}
{{ index }}
{{ field1 }}
{{/each}}
```

The serial number will be displayed at `{{ index }}`

Comment: This will break if you change the sort order of you groups. Why not just use {{_id}} instead of {{index}}

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
Template.templatename.vname = function(){
    return Groups.find().fetch().map(function (d, i) {
        d._index = i + 1;
        return d;
    });
}
```

**Template**:

```
{{#each vname}}
  {{_index}}
  {{ field1 }}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if we use

```
{{#each vname}}
{{@index }}
{{/each}}
```

Then we will get a serial of numbers beginning from 0,1,2..... to get numbers from 1,2,3... then we can use Handlebar math helper and use below code...

```
{{#each vname}}
{{add @index 1}}
{{/each}}
```

or we write an iterator helper function of our own.